# Can someone explain how inject(Hash.new(0)) { |total, bigram| total[bigram] += 1; total }.sort_by { |_key, value| value }.reverse.to_h works?

Tags: ruby

```
 alphabet = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J",
  "K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T",
  "U","V","W","X","Y","Z"," ",".",",",";",
  "-","'"
]
file = File.read("vt_00.txt")

i = 0
while i < alphabet.count do
  single_char = alphabet[i]
  single_char_count = file.count(single_char)
  print "#{alphabet[i]} = #{single_char_count} "
  j = 0
  while j < alphabet.count do
    two_chars = alphabet[i] + alphabet[j]  
    two_chars_count = file.scan(two_chars).count
    if two_chars_count > 10 && two_chars_count < 15
      print "#{two_chars} = #{two_chars_count} "
    end
    k = 0
    while k < alphabet.count do
      three_chars = alphabet[i] + alphabet[j] + alphabet[k]
      three_chars_count = file.scan(three_chars).count
      if three_chars_count > 10 && three_chars_count < 15
        print "#{three_chars} = #{three_chars_count} "
      end
      k += 1
    end
    j += 1
  end
  i += 1
end
```

I had code like upper code. But then I found a solution through each_cons, can u explain how it works?
I don't understand .inject.. part.

```
count = string.each_cons(1).inject(Hash.new(0)) { |total, bigram| total[bigram] += 1; total }.sort_by {  |_key, value| value }.reverse.to_h
```

Comment: ^ https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject

Comment: `each_cons`  on a string? Must be an ancient Ruby version.

Comment: Aside from @steenslag's point, this is the first time I've seen `each_cons(1)` used, which is equivalent to `each`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more elaborate way to write it would be:

```
total = Hash.new(0)
string.each_cons(1).each{|bigram| total[bigram] += 1}
```

`inject` allows to inject some start value (`Hash.new(0)` --> we use the default 0 so we can safely use the `+=` operator), and whatever the block returns is injected in the next iteration. So in this case we have to explicitly return the hash (`total`) to be able to manipulate it in the next step.

A simple example is adding all values of an array:

```
 [1,4,5,23,2,66,123].inject(0){|sum, value| sum += value}
```

We start with 0, the first iteration we execute `0 + 1` and the result of that will then be injected in the next iteration.

Note: in your original code, instead of using `while` loops and maintaining counters, you could more easily iterate over the arrays as follows:

```
 alphabet.each do |single_char|
   single_char_count = file.count(single_char)
   print "#{alphabet[i]} = #{single_char_count} "
   alphabet.each do |second_char| 
     two_chars = single_char + second_char  
     # do something with two_chars 
     alphabet.each do |third_char|
       three_chars = single_char + second-char + third_char
       # do something with three_chars
     end 
   end
 end
```

I am guessing it depends on the size of the `file` whether iterating over all `each_cons` (1-2-3) or using `file.scan` will be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

**The question**

You wish to know how the following works:

```
g = Hash.new(0)
count = str.each_char.inject(g) do |h, s|
  h[s] += 1
  h
end.sort_by { |_key, value| value }.reverse.to_h
```

`str.each_cons(1)` does not work because the class `String`, of which `str` is an instance, does not have an instance method `each_cons`. There is a method [Enumerable#each_cons](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons), but the class `String` does not `include` that module, so strings to not respond to that method:

```
String.included_modules
  #=> [Comparable, Kernel]
```

[String#each_char](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-each_char) does make sense here, as it returns an enumerator that generates each character of the string. I therefore assume that `each_char` was meant where `each_cons(1)` was written.

I have changed the variable names to something more generic, and have moved

```
g = Hash.new(0)
```

to a separate line.

**An example**

Suppose `str` is as follows:

```
str = "The Cat and the Hat"
```

**Examine steps performed**

Let's break the calculation into pieces:

```
g = Hash.new(0)
  #=> {}
h = str.each_char.inject(g) do |h,s|
  h[s] += 1
  h
end
  #=> {"T"=>1, "h"=>2, "e"=>2, " "=>4, "C"=>1,
  #    "a"=>3, "t"=>3, "n"=>1, "d"=>1, "H"=>1}
a = h.sort_by { |_key, value| value }
  #=> [["T", 1], ["C", 1], ["n", 1], ["d", 1], ["H", 1],
  #    ["h", 2], ["e", 2], ["a", 3], ["t", 3], [" ", 4]] 
b = a.reverse
  #=> [[" ", 4], ["t", 3], ["a", 3], ["e", 2], ["h", 2],
  #    ["H", 1], ["d", 1], ["n", 1], ["C", 1], ["T", 1]] 
count = b.to_h
  #=> {" "=>4, "t"=>3, "a"=>3, "e"=>2, "h"=>2,
  #    "H"=>1, "d"=>1, "n"=>1, "C"=>1, "T"=>1}
```

The calculations of `a`, `b` and `count` are straightforward, so let's consider them first.

**Calculation of `a`**

Like all `Enumerable` methods, [Enumerable#sort_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) requires that its receiver responds to the method `each`. Here `sort_by`'s receiver is a hash so `h` must respond to [Hash#each](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-each). Indeed, `sort_by`'s first operation is to convert `h` to an enumerator by sending it the method `Hash#each`:

```
enum = h.each
  #=> #<Enumerator: {"T"=>1, "h"=>2, "e"=>2, " "=>4, "C"=>1, "a"=>3,
  #                  "t"=>3, "n"=>1, "d"=>1, "H"=>1}:each>
```

We can see the values that are generated by this enumerator by repeatedly sending it the method [Enumerator#next](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-next):

```
enum.next  #=> ["T", 1] 
enum.next  #=> ["h", 2] 
enum.next  #=> ["e", 2] 
...
enum.next  #=> ["H", 1] 
enum.next  #=> StopIteration (iteration reached an end)
```

It is seen that `enum` generates a sequence of the hash's key-value pairs. Therefore,

```
h.sort_by { |_key, value| value }
```

is equivalent to

```
[["T", 1], ["h", 2], ["e", 2],..., ["H", 1]].sort_by { |_key, value| value }
```

which explains why `a` equals the array shown above.

**Calculation of `b`**

This calculation could not be more straightforward. Note that we could save a step by replacing `b = h.sort_by { |_key, value| value }.reverse` with

```
b = h.sort_by { |_key, value| -value }
  #=> [[" ", 4], ["a", 3], ["t", 3], ["h", 2], ["e", 2],
  #    ["T", 1], ["C", 1], ["n", 1], ["d", 1], ["H", 1]]
```

This sorts the the key-value pairs of `h` in decreasing order of value, as before, though ties are ordered somewhat differently.

**Calculation of `count`**

This is a straightforward application of the method [Array#to_h](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-to_h).

**Calculation of `h`**

The first step in this calculation is to use the method [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-c-new) to create an empty hash with a *default value* of zero:

```
h = Hash.new(0)
  #=> {}
```

This simply causes `h[k]` to return the default value of zero when `h` does not have a key `k`. For example, since `h` now has no keys:

```
h['cat']
  #=> 0
```

If we now set

```
h['cat'] = 3
```

then

```
h['cat']
  #=> 3
```

as the default value no longer applies. A hash `h` created this way is often called a *counting hash*. Ruby's first step in parsing the expression `h[s] += 1` is to expand it to:

```
h[s] = h[s] + 1
```

If `h` does not have a key `s` the expression reduces to

```
h[s] = 0 + 1
```

because `h[s]` on the right of the equals sign (the method [Hash#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D), as contrasted with the method [Hash#[]=](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) on the left) returns the default value of zero. If the string were `"aaa"`, the following calculations would be made:

```
h['a'] = h['a'] + 1 => 0 + 1 => 1
h['a'] = h['a'] + 1 => 1 + 1 => 2
h['a'] = h['a'] + 1 => 2 + 1 => 3
```

`h['a']` on the right returns the default value of zero in the first step, but since `h` then has the key `'a'` in the second and third steps the current values of `h['a']` are returned after the first step.

[Enumerable#inject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) (a.k.a `reduce`) can be used here but the calculation of `h` is more commonly written as follows:

```
h = str.each_char.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |s,h| h[s] += 1 }
  #=> {"T"=>1, "h"=>2, "e"=>2, " "=>4, "C"=>1,
  #    "a"=>3, "t"=>3, "n"=>1, "d"=>1, "H"=>1}
```

See [Enumerable#each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object).